# I have a variable declared and given a value in one php file, how can I use that variable with the value stored in it in another php file?

Tags: php

the website is like a social media.

The first php file does the log in, and it will have a variable $name1 where the username of the logged on user will be stored

I need to that same variable with the username value stored in it in another php file where I create a query containing all the posts from that user.

How can I use that variable in my second php file?

Comment: sessions are the most common approach to something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Uses Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

in login.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $name1;
```

on nextPage.php

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: so when I am in nextPage.php the variable name I use will be $username, right?

Comment: Well yes/no.  Yes using that code. The variable is in the session array.  You have to assign it to $username or whatever variable you want using ___ = $_SESSION['user'];

Answer (score 2):

Just use the session and store in it username and than you will have access to it in any php file when you start the session.

Comment: how can I do that? This is my first project, I have never used it before

Comment: @Noha spend a few hours in the manual section on sessions, http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php and doing some of your own research, then re-ask this if you encounter a specific question, this is really yo broad for a good S.O question